# toml configuration for Selenium node not working when setting proxy option

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, jmeter, geckodriver, toml

I'm desperately trying to start a Selenium node (Selenium standalone 4.13.0) in order to run some performance tests through the jmeter/jmeter-server tool (via rmi) using a remote Linux vm. I have to start the sessions of firefox using a custom proxy setting, so i tried to launch the selenium node including the reference of a toml config file in CL.

I wrote this file this way, trying to insert correctly what needs to set the proxy:

```
[node]
detect-drivers = false

[[node.driver-configuration]]
display-name = "firefox"
stereotype = "{\"browserName\": \"firefox\", \"browserVersion\": \"118\", \"platformName\": \"LINUX\", \"acceptSslCerts\": true, \"acceptInsecureCerts\": true, \"proxy\": {\"httpProxy\": \"http://...:80\", \"proxyType\": \"manual\", \"noProxy\": \"172.*;*.local\"}, \"moz:firefoxOptions\": {\"binary\": \"/usr/local/firefox/firefox-bin\"}}"
log-level = "trace"
webdriver-executable = "/usr/local/bin/geckodriver"
session-timeout = 30
```

What's important is that i necessarily need to specify the "noProxy" field to insert the list of exceptions.
Anyway every time I try to start the test remotely, it gets stuck, as it seems the remote web driver cannot communicate with selenium grid.

The complete log of selenium-server is this:

```
2023-10-02 12:56:58,417 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'BDM_AS_01', ip: '10.6.197.103'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.RemoteDriverConfig.createBrowser(RemoteDriverConfig.java:25) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.RemoteDriverConfig.createBrowser(RemoteDriverConfig.java:13) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:221) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:152) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:797) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:993) ~[jorphan.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976) ~[jorphan.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:765) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:753) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:264) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_345'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:65) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42) ~[selenium-http-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56) ~[selenium-http-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:49) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42) ~[selenium-http-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56) ~[selenium-http-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:99) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.TracedHttpClient.execute(TracedHttpClient.java:55) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:124) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:165) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1784) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1928) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:206) ~[async-http-client-2.12.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:59) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42) ~[selenium-http-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56) ~[selenium-http-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:49) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42) ~[selenium-http-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56) ~[selenium-http-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:99) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.TracedHttpClient.execute(TracedHttpClient.java:55) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:124) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:165) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
    ... 14 more
2023-10-02 12:56:58,426 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: credenziali_front.csv
2023-10-02 12:56:58,427 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'Clear Cookie (in attesa di LOGOUT)'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured.  Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is created for a ThreadGroup.
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:65) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
2023-10-02 12:56:58,427 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'Login'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured.  Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is created for a ThreadGroup.
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:65) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
2023-10-02 12:56:58,427 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'Logout'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured.  Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is created for a ThreadGroup.
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:65) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.10.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
```

The final error is that the browser has not been configured properly. Where is the mistake? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I don't add all the information about proxy settings in the line containing "sterotype", the test starts correctly, but stops in the second step because it needs proxy configs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) you don't need to start Firefox instances yourself, [Firefox Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FirefoxDriverConfig/) takes care of it. It is also possible to specify proxy settings there:

[image]

Also be informed that:

- It's [not recommended to use Selenium for performance testing by Selenium developers](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/)

  > Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.
- It's [not recommended to use Selenium for performance testing by WebDriver Sampler developers](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/)

  > Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

So I would rather recommend considering [configuring JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) and using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers for this. You will produce the same network footprint with much less resources.

Comment: I'm not using Firefox Driver Config, but Remote Driver Config, connecting remotely to Selenium Grid to execute my tests. Anyway, I'm forced to use this stack to execute my performance test: Jmeter starting remotely the Jmeter-server that is hosted in Linux VM, which calls Selenium Grid, instantiating a new firefox session through a Selenium Node (after set all the firefox capabilities and geckodriver location in a toml config file).

Comment: Remote Driver Config has the same proxy configuration. Also you might need to tick `Headless` box if your system doesn't have GUI

Comment: Anyway, in this config page I cannot pass proxy's username/password. So when the browser session starts executing the automated test, firefox asks me proxy's username/password in a dialog window, which is blocking for the test. That's because through Jmeter test's script is not possibile to set username/password if an another window element, different from the current web page, appears. So, how can i bypass this problem?